# Warning Popup when editing an answer: Changes that you made may not be saved

Tags: bug, edits

When I am trying to edit a question, on clicking `Save Edits` button, I am getting following popup:

[image: error message leave site]

It should only come when I close that tab, however it is showing when I click on "Save Edits" button.

Comment: Disable all browser plugins/extensions/userscripts and try again. I'm 99% sure it will work. Then enable them one by one until you find which cause this issue, and post as self answer so others will know to disable it. (As a bonus, report to whoever wrote the plugin/extension/userscript and let them know it breaks SE.)

Comment: I am not expert in programming but becuase you said that this is warning Popup , could youy explain me why? I do not got it your problem